# if necessary past verb?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, phrases

I read this sentence:

> This covering up of pipes is all a mistake, they should be exposed
>   everywhere, ***if necessary painted*** well and handsomely.

It uses a use of "if necessary" I have never seen before. I searched it up, but found no results. Don't we usually use "if necessary" by itself? I don't know how a past participle can be used after "if necessary".

I think the full version of the phrase should be something like

*if (it is) necessary (to be) painted*.

But is it a common usage? Is it grammatical? It was written in 19th century, so I don't know if this usage is still used.

The book is called The Devil In The White City, and it is said by Peter Chardon Brooks III in a letter (a real letter -- the book is non fiction).

Comment: What is the source? Specifically, who is saying this, and in what context. The tenses seem to be a bit messed up.

Comment: @user3169 The book is called The Devil In The White City, and it is said by Peter Chardon Brooks III in a letter (a real letter -- the book is non fiction).

Comment: OK, please add this info. to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This passage is from a letter in which a client instructs his architects about many details of the building he wants. It is a very long letter, and the client is setting down his ideas in a hurry, so he doesn't bother with minor details of punctuation and sentence structure. What he means would be more formally expressed something like this; I've highlighted my changes:

> This covering up of pipes is all a mistake`;` they should be exposed everywhere`—`if necessary painted well and handsomely.

In this context *if necessary* is an entirely acceptable and quite ordinary abbreviation of the phrase *if it is necessary*. As Brooks' comma (or my dash)  indicates, this final phrase is a *supplement* inserted as a parenthetical qualification. *If necessary* indicates that the pipes should be *painted* only if that is necessary.

And *painted* here is not a past-tense verb but a past participle. You may read it either as an adjectival modifying *pipes* or as a second complement to passivizing *be*. The difference between those two readings is of interest only to formal grammarians.

Comment: @ColinFine Your reading, with *and*, was exactly my original thought; but then I reconsidered and decided that the whole last piece was supplemental.

Comment: Thank you. I just have never seen "if necessary + ed" construction. Could you show me the grammatical structure behind it? Can I say something like "the building will be done everything it requires, if necessary covered with gold". I think something is elided...but I don't know what is.

Comment: @whitedevil *If necessary* doesn't "construct" with the participle but with the phrase which the participle heads--you could just as well put it at the end: *The pipes should be exposed--painted handsomely, if necessary*. It's the same construction as "I'd like my bread toasted--buttered, if possible*.

Comment: Thank you! That's where I was confused. I think a comma after if necessary would have been clearer, but it was written hurriedly :)

Comment: @whitedevil I'm not a big fan of short comma parentheticals unless they're really necessary to avoid ambiguity or structure the train of thought. From what I see of his style I don't think Brooks would **say** this with comma intonation. It amounts to "If you think you have to you can paint it".